# How to solve a "BAD REQUEST" error while trying to import data from a hyperlink in excel using macros?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, bad-request

I want to import some data from a website https://www.amfiindia.com/nav-history-download. On this page, there is a link "Download Complete NAV Report in Text Format" which will give me the required data. But this link is not static so I cannot use this directly in VBA to download my data. So how to download data from a hyperlink on a webpage using excel?

My approach is first getting the hyperlink in a variable then use that variable to get the data?

1. First, get the hyperlink using the getElementsByTagName function as shown below.
2. Then use that as URL to get the data.

But I am getting the "BAD REQUEST" response while I am sending a request to this hyperlink. I don't know why this error is coming. The code I used is

```
Sub GrabLastNames()

    'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim mtbl As String
    Dim request As Object
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim price As Variant
    Dim cellAddress As String
    Dim rowNumber As Long



    'start a new browser instance
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make browser visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate "https://www.amfiindia.com/nav-history-download"
    'wait for page to load
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ' ht.querySelector(".nav-hist-dwnld a").href
    'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
    y = 1
    mtbl = objIE.document.querySelector(".nav-hist-dwnld a").href

    ' mtbl = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value

    ' Website to go to.
    ' website = mtbl

    ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
    request.Open "GET", mtbl, False


    ' Get fresh data.
    request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

    ' Send the request for the webpage.
    request.send

    '    MsqBox "bye"

    ' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
    response = request.responseText



    ' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
    'html.body.innerHTML = response

     MsgBox "Hi"
    '   MsgBox "Bye Bye"

    ' Get the price from the specified element on the page.

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y + 1).Value = "Hi"

    MsgBox response


    'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
    'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

The response variable should have all the data from the website but instead, it is printing this "Bad Request" in msgBox.

Comment: What is the value of `mtbl`?

Comment: Did you check mtbl is a full url and whether any headers are required for the request?

Comment: mtbl has the url from which I want to import data. This url is not static. Right now the mtbl had  https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t=06052020095056   this link

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, I checked the headers and I conctenated it with the hyperlink like this:  ```mtbl = objIE.document.querySelector(".nav-hist-dwnld a").href
                  Header = "https://www.amfiindia.com"
                  website = Header & mtbl ``` Now I am not getting the bad request error but it is saying a new error ```The  system cannot locate the resource specified``` .

Comment: That is not what I meant by header.  Your url is fine and complete. You set headers like this: https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ i.e. with .setrequestheader method. I see this header info: https://pastebin.com/TmSUn9vk. It is unlikely you need all of that but most likely for a 403 you need the user agent. e.g. .setRequestHeader "User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0"

Comment: @QHarr This Worked. Thanks a lot. I just added the setRequestHeader and was able to get the data in excel. I added this request header ```"User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"```

Comment: No worries. Have written up below as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set headers like [this](http://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba)  i.e. with `.setrequestheader` method.

I see this header info:

```
GET /spages/NAVAll.txt?t=06052020095056 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amfiindia.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=57940026.1471746098.1588710696.1588710696.1588710696.1; __utmc=57940026; __utmz=57940026.1588710696.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
If-None-Match: "0d8e9bad223d61:0"
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 06 May 2020 18:18:24 GMT
```

It is unlikely you need all of that but most likely for a 403 you need the user agent. e.g. .`setRequestHeader "User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0"`